# Why is my Windows 8.1 start button green?

Tags: windows-8.1

I understand that this button looks green when there is some sort of update, but both Windows Update and the Windows Store have been fully updated.

[image]

What other programs can turn my Windows start button green? it is both green in the charms bar and when mousing over it on the task bar.

I have now updated my GPU drivers, the problem is still there. I have rebooted my PC, the problem is still there. It is also there in safe mode. As far as I know, this is not default behavior for Windows 8.1.

I figured out that the color is linked to whatever my start screen color is. I still have no idea why it changes color though.

Comment: I assume you have tried to restart your device?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I have. This button has been like this for a few weeks now. I am restarting it now to make sure that it's not of temporary nature. And after a reboot, it's still the case for both the task bar and the charms bar buttons.

Comment: Congrats, your machine is running on eco-friendly current. Green "thumb"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Phew, this question has been here for a while...*

The color of your start button is based on your Accent Color in your personalized color scheme.

To change this, Open the Metro Start Menu. Then, open the Charms Bar, Press Settings, then press Personalize. You can then pick a new accent color.

Did this help?

Comment: I kinda remember it not always being colored according to my accent color. Doesn't it only get a color when there's some kind of software update? Or does it always have this color?

Comment: It always has the color, it's just that it gained the color first in the Windows 8.1 update.

Comment: I see. So it doesn't have anything to do with there being some kind of update available for one program or the other?

Comment: Nope, not at all.